# Pass element (as jQuery object) as argument to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function to mouse click elements.

Lets consider `$(element).click()` out of this question's scope now, I want to create it this way:

```
function mouseClick() {
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });

    var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

mouseClick();
```

**The problem is:**

When I try to pass elements as arguments to this function (as a jQuery object), when I'm calling it:

```
function mouseClick(element) {
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });

    //var element = document.getElementById('elementId'); <==== I want to remove this to replace it with the arguments when I call it;
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

var element = $('#elementId');
mouseClick(element);
```

I get the console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function

But when I select the elements using `getElementById` it works:

```
var element = $('#elementId'); //<==== this doesn't work;
var element = document.getElementById('elementId'); //<==== this works;
mouseClick(element);
```

Why is this happening?

And how can I make the jQuery selectors way works?

Basically I want to select elements in more advanced ways beyond the ID selector, so, I think jQuery comes handy and write less.

Comment: `dispatchEvent` is a DOM method, not a jQuery method.

Comment: jQuery has a `trigger` method that's similar to `dispatchEvent`.

Comment: @Barmar would you please give an example for how to use the jQuery `trigger`?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery objects are not the same as DOM elements, and you generally can't call the same methods on them (there are a few cases where they have similar methods with the same name, e.g. `submit()` for forms). `dispatchEvent()` is a DOM method, not a jQuery method, so you can't call it on a jQuery object.

You can get the DOM element from a jQuery object using the `get()` method, so you can do:

```
mouseClick(element.get(0));
```

You can also use subscripting as a shortcut:

```
mouseClick(element[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of a `jquery` selector is not a `DOM` element, so you can't use `displayEvent` on it.

You can go over all the elements in your `jquery` selector and apply dispatch the event to every one of them:

```
Object.keys(element).forEach(function(key) {
    element[key].dispatchEvent(event);
});
```